# Google GET /drive/v2/about Capacity Incorrect

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

When I `GET` this endpoint `/drive/v3/about?fields=storageQuota` to check my storage usage, it incorrectly returns the storage capacity used by the account.

I have a google account that I use purely to programmatically add images/videos into Photos. No use of Google Drive, or Gmail (aside from the few confirmation emails amounting to negligible size).

Is the following scenario a bug with the API? Or is there a way to force an update of the value, like commit in a db connection? Or am I using the API correctly + is there a more appropriate endpoint (I have not found one)?

My python code:

```
def get_storage_capacity():
    response = session.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=storageQuota')
    content = response._content.decode("utf-8")
    parsed_content = json.loads(content)
    storage_quota = parsed_content["storageQuota"]
    storage_available = int(storage_quota["limit"])/(1024*1024*1024)  # convert to MB
    storage_used = int(storage_quota["usage"])/(1024*1024*1024)
    storage_used_percent = (storage_used/storage_available) * 100
    print(f"storage_available: {storage_available}GB")
    print(f"storage_used: {storage_used}GB")
    print(f"storage_used_percent: {storage_used_percent}%")
    insert_drive_metrics(storage_available, storage_used, storage_used_percent)
```

Returns:

```
storage_available: 200.0GB
storage_used: 116.30095641314983GB
storage_used_percent: 58.15047820657492%
```

Which **APPEARS** to be correct when viewing the lefthand side of any google service that uses storage:
[image: Incorrect Capacity Value]

Except this is obviously incorrect because **a) the value has not changed in the five days since i've started recording the metric, despite 24/7 uploads, and b) the storage page where you buy more storage shows the *actual* correct value as seen here**:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using v2?

Comment: @DaImTo Was trying both and that's what I ended up pasting -- v3 returns the same results. Exec'd `/drive/v3/about?fields=storageQuota`  just now and returned 

```
 },
 "storageQuota": {
  "limit": "214748364800",
  "usage": "124877201072",
  "usageInDrive": "0",
  "usageInDriveTrash": "0"
 },
```

which is the same value for usage (after  / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 )

Comment: I've updated the post to show v3 so as to not detract from the merit of this question